# How to replace a word in a sentence based on a condition in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component for the header of my website that says (Good morning, I'm John,   Thank you for visiting my website, please contact me if you need more information).

in the first line it says Good morning I am trying to change it based on user current time to say good afternoon and good evening. I already have code below but not sure how to implement it here just changing that only word while keeping the rest of my paragraph

```
let today = new Date()
let curHr = today.getHours()
if (curHr < 12) {
<h1> Good morning <h1>
} else if (curHr < 18) {
<h1> Good afteroon <h1>
} else {
<h1> Good evening <h1>
}



import React, { Component } from "react";
class MainHeader extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="my_header">
      <h3> Good morning, I'm john Thank you for visiting my website, please contact me if you need more information </h3>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MainHeader;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the code above into a reusable function, and then just create a new greeting on each rerender. Then just display in the render with curly brackets.

```
function generateGreeting(){
  let today = new Date()
  let curHr = today.getHours()
  if (curHr < 12) {
     return 'Good morning'
  } else if (curHr < 18) {
     return 'Good afteroon'
  } else {
     return 'Good evening'
  }
}

import React, { Component } from "react";
class MainHeader extends Component {
  render() {
    const greeting = generateGreeting();
    return (
      <div className="my_header">
      <h3> <h1>{greeting}</h1>, I'm john Thank you for visiting my website, please contact me if you need more information </h3>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MainHeader;
```

Comment: Thank you very much all, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You could update your code to invoke a method from the React component like so:

```
class MainHeader extends Component {
  getTimeOfDay() {
    // your conditional checks here
    if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) > 500) {
      return "morning";
    }

    return "afternoon";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="my_header">
      <h3> Good {this.getTimeOfDay()}, I'm john Thank you for visiting my website, please contact me if you need more information </h3>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";

  let today = new Date()
  let curHr = today.getHours()


  class MainHeader extends Component {
      render() {
        let headline = "Good evening";

        if(curHr < 12) {
          headline = "Good morning";
        }

        if(curHr > 12 && curHr < 18) {
          headline = "Good afternoon";
        }

        return (
          <div className="my_header">
            <h1>{headline}</h1>
            <h3>I'm john Thank you for visiting my website, please contact me if you need more information </h3>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default MainHeader;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
function getGreetings() {
    let today = new Date()
    let curHr = today.getHours()
    if (curHr < 12) {
        return  <h1> Good morning <h1> 
    } else if (curHr < 18) {
       return <h1> Good afteroon <h1>
    } else { 
       return <h1> Good evening <h1> 
    }
```

And in your render function:

```
render() { 
    return ( 
        <div className="my_header">
             <h3> {getGreetings ()}, I'm john Thank you for visiting my website, please contact me if you need more information </h3> 
        </div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const today = new Date();
const curHr = today.getHours();
let message;
if (curHr < 12) {
    message = <h1> Good morning </h1>;
} else if (curHr < 18) {
    message = <h1> Good afteroon </h1>;
} else {
    message = <h1> Good evening </h1>;
}

class MainHeader extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="my_header">
        {message}
        <h3>I'm john Thank you for visiting my website, please contact me if you need more information </h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/agustin107/h0qbL7k5/2/